# Convert a keyword to a string

Tags: python

I have a keywords list which was edited from [7. Simple statements — Python 3.6.3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html)

```
simple_stmt_list = [assert,pass,del,return,yield,raise,break,
                    continue,import,global,nonlocal]
```

The result I need is

```
simple_stmt_list =['assert', 'pass', 'del', 'return', 'yield', 
                'raise', 'break', 'continue', 'import', 'global', 'nonlocal']
```

When I tried to manipulate the list

```
In [14]: simple_stmt_list = [assert,pass,del,return,yield,raise,break,continue,import,global,nonlocal
    ...: ]
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I searched around but failed to get a solution to the problem in python.

I have to change the list to string manually,
change `[]` to `''`,like

```
In [15]: simple_stmt= 'assert,pass,del,return,yield,raise,break,continue,import,global,nonlocal'
In [19]: print(simple_stmt.split(','))
['assert', 'pass', 'del', 'return', 'yield', 'raise', 'break', 'continue', 'import', 'global', 'nonlocal']
```

How to solve such a problem elegantly?

Comment: this last thing you did is quite elegant.

Comment: Keywords are part of the language, which means you cannot name variables after them or manipulate them that way. AFAIK, there is no better solution than the one you are currently using.